# How to pass javascript function value across php webpages

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, variables

So I'm creating a registration form that calculates the totalPrice using javascript based on the user's selections, and returns the value and stores it as a class (called totalPrice).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"/></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="paymentform" action="Session5.php" method="post">
   <label><b>Camp Sessions: 1-6 (Check off the week(s) the camper will be participating in.)</b> </label><br /><br />
   <ol>
   <li>July 8 - July 12 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July8-July12" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek1"></li>
   <li>July 15 - July 19 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July15-July19" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek2"></li>
   <li>July 22 - July 26 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July22-July26" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek3"></li>
   <li>July 29 - August 2 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July29-August2" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek4"></li>
   <li>August 6 - August 9 ($60/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="August6-August9" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek5"></li>
  <li>August 12 - August 16 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="August12-August16" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek6"></li>
   </ol>

   <label> <b> Include After Camp Care? </b></label> <input type="checkbox" name= "campcare" onclick="getTotal()" id="aftercampcare" /> <br /><br />
   <i> After Camp Care is available from 4pm-6pm for an additional charge of $2/hr.</i><br /><br />

      Total Price:<div class="inline totalPrice"> </div>
      <br/>



<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" class="button greenButton"/>
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="button redButton" onclick="href='activemindandbody.org'">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript code, in Javascript.js:

```
function weekPrice()
{
    var weekPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["paymentform"];
    var includeWeek1 = theForm.elements["includeweek1"];
    var includeWeek2 = theForm.elements["includeweek2"];
    var includeWeek3 = theForm.elements["includeweek3"];
    var includeWeek4 = theForm.elements["includeweek4"];
    var includeWeek5 = theForm.elements["includeweek5"];
    var includeWeek6 = theForm.elements["includeweek6"];
    var afterCampCare = theForm.elements["aftercampcare"];


    if(includeWeek1.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek2.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek3.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek4.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek5.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 60;
    }
    if (includeWeek6.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (afterCampCare.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 2;
    }
    return weekPrice;
}
function getTotal()
{
var weekTotalPrice = weekPrice(); 
document.getElementsByClassName("totalPrice")[0].innerHTML = "" + weekTotalPrice;
}
```

**Here's my problem: On the next page, I need the value of totalPrice again, and need to output it on html. On the page after that, I need to store the same value into the database. So, how can I store a Javascript function value using php, so I use various php functions?**

Comment: You create a php file which saves your variable in DB and use js (ajax)  to send your variable to that script.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the hint : Once submitted, the value can be stored as a $_SESSION value in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML page, add the following between the `<form>` and `</form>` tags:

`<input type="hidden" name="totalprice" />`

In your JavaScript, inside the `getTotal()` function, add the following line (after setting weekTotalPrice):

`document.querySelector('input[type=hidden][name=totalprice]').value = weekTotalPrice;`

Then when you submit your form, this field will be sent over too!

You could access it on the next page using PHP by doing this:

`<?php echo($_POST['totalprice']); ?>`

You could add it to another hidden field by doing this:

`<input type="hidden" name="totalprice" value="<?php echo($_POST['totalprice']); ?>" />`

Comment: thanks azcn but the echo function doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: On the next page, place this code to see which fields were posted successfully: `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` - if you do not see `['totalprice']` in the array then it probably was not submitted and cannot be echoed. Maybe an error is being logged to the php error log file? The location of this can vary depending on OS and user config.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the JavaScript function to set the total value as a hidden input field value on the first page form, then on the next page retrieve the POST'ed value and pass it into another hidden field which you can then use to store the value into the database.